# Baker "Did not find service" Error

Tags: baking, node, baker

When starting my baker I use the command:

```
./tezos-baker-003-PsddFKi3 -d /home/account/.tezos-client run with local node /home/account/.tezos-node/ baker
```

The output that I'm getting is:

```
Waiting for the node to be synchronized with its peers...
Node synchronized.
Baker started.
Error:
  Did not find service
```

I attempted to add specifics to the command in hopes it just wasn't using the RPC port:

```
./tezos-baker-003-PsddFKi3 -d /home/account/.tezos-client -c /home/account/.tezos-client/config -P 8732 -A 127.0.0.1 run with local node /home/account/.tezos-node/ baker
```

No luck from any of that, still get the same "Did not find service" error.

Comment: Did you moved your data-dir of the node to an other location than /home/[account]/.tezos-node ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your baker cannot find your node. Make sure your node is running on `127.0.0.1:8732`. The baker is a separate service instance, but it needs to fetch data from the node.

Perhaps you can find some useful information [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/289).